# "Refreshing" 8051 Microcontroller :

Tags: c, refresh, project, 8051

```
void main(void)
{
 unsigned char in_char;
   int flag=1,j,i;
   int count, d = 0 ; 
   char s[4]="",p;
   ithul();
   LCD_res();
   init_lcd()
   ;print_lcd(1,"The Project");//Printing command.
   ;print_lcd(2,"of Me:");//Printing command.
   for(i=0; i<20; i++){delay(1000);delay(1000);delay(1000);}
   for(i=0; i<20; i++){delay(1000);delay(1000);delay(1000);}

while(1)
  {
 count = 0;
    loop1 : if(P3_0 == 1){
      goto loop1;
      }
//Running '1' 
    loop2 : if(P3_0 == 0){
      goto loop2;
      }
//Running '0'
    while(P3_0 == 1){
      count ++;
       }
  init_lcd()
   ;print_lcd(1,"Done Counting!");//Printing command.
   for(i=0; i<1; i++){delay(1000);delay(1000);delay(1000);}

   ;print_lcd(2,"    - L/H...");//Printing command.
   for(i=0; i<20; i++){delay(1000);delay(1000);delay(1000);}
   for(i=0; i<20; i++){delay(1000);delay(1000);delay(1000);}
    for(i=0; i<20; i++){delay(1000);delay(1000);delay(1000);}

   ;print_lcd(2,itoa(count/200));//Printing command.
   for(i=0; i<20; i++){delay(1000);delay(1000);delay(1000);}
    for(i=0; i<20; i++){delay(1000);delay(1000);delay(1000);}
   }
}
```

This is my code. What it does is getting Frequency from port, read it and Print it to an LCD.

ITS WORKS! But after like 2 minutes the LCD gets like "asda68!#123646$#$^%&*(dfas" kind of junk!.

How can I refresh the 8051 Microcontroller so it will don't get crazy?
I heard something about 'fresh' 'free' 'flash' commands I think but I really don't know what is or how to use this. SO.. Please help !

Comment: Why have you got semicolons at the beginning of each print line? `free(count)` doesn't do anything except possibly wreck some memory, as `count` is not a pointer.

Comment: You have declared `int count;` so what is `free(count);` expected to do?

Comment: ops sorry I delete that.

Comment: In any case you should be using a timer register (preferably with edge-triggered capture) to measure frequency, not a software loop.

Comment: Shouldn't `itoa()` take a string parameter?

Comment: this itoa() get a number/int and turn it into arr of char.

Comment: for example324 int turns to {3, 2 ,4}

Comment: What does your language manual tell you about `itoa()`? In the following 8051 compiler reference it is `char *itoa(int number, char* string, int radix);`. So you'll be passing an imaginary string pointer and sooner or later get a failure. What compiler warnings do you get? http://www.crossware.com/smanuals/c8051/_itoa.html

Comment: how can I send u the full function ? I got it works.
this is itoa changed by me

Answer (score 1):

Your function:

```
char * itoa( int x ) { 
    const unsigned int BASE = 10; 
    unsigned int u = abs( x ); 
    size_t n = 0; 
    unsigned int tmp = u; 
    char *s; 
    do { ++n; } 
    while ( tmp /= BASE ); 
    n += x < 0; 
    s = malloc( ( n + 1 ) * sizeof( char ) ); 
    s[n] = 0; 
    do { s[--n] = u % BASE + '0'; } 
    while ( u /= BASE ); 
    if ( x < 0 ) s[--n] = '-'; 
    return s;
}
```

Every time you call `itoa()` it allocates more memory for the string `s` and after a while it runs out of memory *but never checks the return value from `malloc()`*. You need to put `free()` back into the program.

```
char *strg;
...
strg = itoa (count / 200);
print_lcd(2,strg);
free(strg);
```

So the whole code will look like this, see where commented.

```
void main(void) {
    char *strg;                 // new variable
    unsigned char in_char;
    int flag=1,j,i;
    int count, d = 0 ; 
    char s[4]="",p;
    ithul();
    LCD_res();
    init_lcd();
    print_lcd(1,"The Project");//Printing command.
    print_lcd(2,"of Me:");//Printing command.
    for(i=0; i<20; i++){delay(1000);delay(1000);delay(1000);}
    for(i=0; i<20; i++){delay(1000);delay(1000);delay(1000);}

    while(1) {
        count = 0;
        loop1 : if(P3_0 == 1){
            goto loop1;
        }
        //Running '1' 
        loop2 : if(P3_0 == 0){
            goto loop2;
        }
        //Running '0'
        while(P3_0 == 1){
            count ++;
        }
        init_lcd();
        print_lcd(1,"Done Counting!");//Printing command.
        for(i=0; i<1; i++){delay(1000);delay(1000);delay(1000);}

        print_lcd(2,"    - L/H...");//Printing command.
        for(i=0; i<20; i++){delay(1000);delay(1000);delay(1000);}
        for(i=0; i<20; i++){delay(1000);delay(1000);delay(1000);}
        for(i=0; i<20; i++){delay(1000);delay(1000);delay(1000);}

        strg = itoa (count / 200);  // keep the returned pointer
        print_lcd(2,strg);          // display the "frequency"
        free(strg);                 // free the pointer memory
        for(i=0; i<20; i++){delay(1000);delay(1000);delay(1000);}
        for(i=0; i<20; i++){delay(1000);delay(1000);delay(1000);}
    }
}
```

Comment: I get an error:
non pointer type cast to generic pointer from type 'int'

Comment: Can you be a little more specific?

Comment: I'm sorry. I new here and don't get yet all function of the site!|
BTW Great people here!
so.. Why it get that error.?

Comment: Which line gives the error? This is getting uphill ;-) Please spell it out in black and white.

Comment: wait a sec .. hehe... where do I need to add the 'free' line command?

Comment: @ShayShtern see revised answer.

Comment: So I need to write the command free... afrer the printing?
not in the function 'itoa'?
I just want to make sure that.

Comment: Why would you free it before you have used it? See my answer. If it works, please "accept" the answer, upvote it, etc., to reward my time. Thanks!

Comment: opssi , I get u wrong... My fault..
I'm trying again.. replay in few minutes .. THANKS ALOT ANYWAY
I APPRECIATEDֱ
so.. I still get the Junk LCD...
The C code passing compail .